# Fail to load a .pth file (pre-trained neural network) using torch.load() on google colab

Tags: deep-learning, google-drive-api, pytorch, google-colaboratory, ioerror

My google drive is linked to my google colab notebook. Using the pytorch library torch.load($PATH)  fails to load this 219 Mo file (pre-trained neural network) (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-9m4aVg8Hze0IsZRyxvm5gLybuRLJHv-) which is in my google drive. However it works fine when I do it locally on my computer. The error i get on google collab is: (settings: Python 3.6, pytorch 1.3.1):

````
state_dict = torch.load(model_path)['state_dict']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 303, in load
return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 454, in _load
return legacy_load(f)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 380, in legacy_load
with closing(tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='r:', format=tarfile.PAX_FORMAT)) as tar,
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 1589, in open
return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 1619, in taropen
return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 1482, in init
self.firstmember = self.next()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2297, in next
tarinfo = self.tarinfo.fromtarfile(self)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 1092, in fromtarfile
buf = tarfile.fileobj.read(BLOCKSIZE)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error```   




Any help would be much appreciated!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by uploading directly the file to google colab instead of loading it from google drive using:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded= files.upload()
```

I guess this solution is similar to the one proposed by @Yuri

Answer (score 0):

Large sized files are automatically analyzed for virus on Drive, every time you attempt to download a large file you have to pass thru this scan, making it hard to reach the download link.

You could download the file directly using the Drive API and then pass it to the torch, it shouldn't be hard to implement on Python, I've made a sample on how to Download your file and pass it to Torch.

```py
import torch
import pickle
import os.path
import io
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from __future__ import print_function

url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RwpuwNPt_r0M5mQGEw18w-bCfKVwnZrs/view?usp=sharing"
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = (
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    )

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', credentials=creds)

    file_id = '1RwpuwNPt_r0M5mQGEw18w-bCfKVwnZrs'
    request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    # fh = io.BytesIO()
    fh = open('file', 'wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
      status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
      print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
    fh.close()
    torch.load('file')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To run it you'll have first to:

- Enable the Drive API for your account
- Install the Google Drive API libraries,

This takes no more than 3 minutes and is properly explained on the [Quickstart Guide for Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python), just follow steps 1 and 2 and run the provided sample code from above.